# How can I get the intersecting face from two overlapping faces?

Tags: modeling, scripting

I want to have the resulting faces (the orange part) of two faces. How can this be done?
In the end I want to script this but I want to know if there is an operator that could help with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use Boolean modifier on 1 of the planes and select other plane in the modifier tab then choose the Boolean option you need and apply if you want only the mesh being left ***BUT probably you got to make These planes to cubes  and 1 of them must be smaller from hight and after applying the modifier you need just to delete vertices to make it plane again***[image]